# Bell Curve/Gaussian Function/Normal Distribution in TikZ/PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Can anyone tell me how to plot a gaussian function/bell curve using TikZ/PGF? I'm basically looking to implement something like PSTricks's `\psGauss` command.

Comment: great question and great solution, thank you! 
Some days ago I was searching for something like that but only found an example in the TikZ gallery which required gnuplot and did not work for me.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use `pgfplots` to plot the functions. There's no standard macro for it, but the function isn't too complicated and can be added as a `pgfmath` function (based on this answer: [How do I use pgfmathdeclarefunction to create define a new pgf function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-do-i-use-pgfmathdeclarefunction-to-create-define-a-new-pgf-function/15449#15449)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,domain=-2:3,samples=50,smooth}, % All plots: from -2:2, 50 samples, smooth, no marks
  axis x line*=bottom, % no box around the plot, only x and y axis
  axis y line*=left, % the * suppresses the arrow tips
  enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
  \addplot {gauss(0,0.5)};
  \addplot {gauss(1,0.75)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots gauss distribution]

---

In my original answer, I had just declared a normal LaTeX function to the same end:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\gauss[2]{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))} % Gauss function, parameters mu and sigma

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,domain=-2:3,samples=50,smooth}, % All plots: from -2:2, 50 samples, smooth, no marks
axis x line*=bottom, % no box around the plot, only x and y axis
axis y line*=left, % the * suppresses the arrow tips
enlargelimits=upper] % extend the axes a bit to the right and top
\addplot {\gauss{0}{0.5}};
\addplot {\gauss{1}{0.75}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you. No way I would have worked this out on my own.

Comment: Quick fix on the equation.. a bit messy but the post eqn did not work for me.. ``\newcommand\gauss[2]{(1/(#2*(sqrt(2*pi))))*exp(-0.5*(((x-#1)/#2)^2))} % Gauss function, parameters mu and sigma``

Comment: Is there anything similar for Poisson distribution in PGF?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get the Error Missing number treated as zero in line "\end{axis}

Comment: @Adam: It compiles fine for me. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: @Adam: It's best to open a new question for this. Make sure to include the exact code you're trying to compile, and the version number of PGFPlots and TikZ/PGF that you're using.

Comment: How would one make the gauss function take a custom number set as input instead of `x`?