# How do I use pgfmathdeclarefunction to create define a new pgf function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to define new function for `pgf` so I can use it in `pgfplots`.  I'm trying to create a unit pulse function p(x) which has a value of 1 from x=0 to x=1, and 0 elsewhere.

I read the [pgf manual](http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) on Customizing the Mathematical Engine (section 65, page 541), but I'm probably misunderstanding something =P

This code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathand{\pgfmathless{#1}{1}} {\pgfmathgreater{#1}{0}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot {p(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw the same question on the net without an answer and I think that you can't use only functions of pgf 2.00. I hope i'm wrong but ... the question was from C Jorssen and now is a developer in the pgf team.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got it to work by using `pgfmathparse` inside of `pgfmathdeclarefunction`  (I don't know if that's how you're supposed to do it, but I'm satisfied for now)

I can also define it locally using `declare function`.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{and(#1>0, #1<1)}%
}

\begin{document}

My pgf version is: \pgfversion

p(0.2) is \pgfmathparse{p(0.2)}\pgfmathresult

p(2) is \pgfmathparse{p(2)}\pgfmathresult

Plot of p(x):

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-5:5, samples=50]{p(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Using declare function to define localp(x):

\begin{tikzpicture}
[
  declare function={
    localp(\t) = and(\t > 0, \t < 1);
  }
]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-5:5, samples=50]{localp(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: unit pulse plots]

Comment: Excellent work, thanks for sharing that! I've worked this approach into my answer to the question on gauss curves http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11368/2552. Couldn't do it before you posted this!

Comment: very fine and very useful for pgfplots users but I would like to understand why the problem exists if we take the example from the pgfmanual ( double) \pgfmathdouble works  we can use the function with plot inside pgf but not in pgfplots. The error gives something about dim and pt and in the example '\pgfmathreturn\pgf@x` is used to remove pt ... I'm waiting an answer from the author of pgfplots.

Comment: See also Jake's solution in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/using-ifthenelse-in-pgfmath  for more pgfmath insight

Answer (score 8):

I think I can provide some more insight into the questions here.

The good news at first: providing `\begin{axis}[use fpu=false]` will enable you to use all custom math functions (as long as they work in pgf, I guess).

Now the details:
Let me summarize the state of the discussion: 
When we use custom math functions in pgfplots, we have

1. the solution containing `\pgf@x=#1pt`  leads to

   ```
   ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
    
                      Y
   l.24      \addplot[domain=-5:5, samples=50]{double(x)};
   ```
2. The solution with `\pgfmathmultiply{#1}{#1}` worked
3. The solution(s) with `\pgfmathparse` worked as well

   The solution with `\pgfmathand{\pgfmathless{#1}{1}}{\pgfmathgreater{#1}{0}}` failed (in my case something strange with `! Extra  else`

The problem is caused by the fact that PGFPlots has the initial configuration 'use fpu=true'. The fpu is a PGF library; it replaces the math module by something like single precision floating points.

As long as user contributed math functions rely only on high-level math functions (like `\pgfmathparse` or `\pgfmathmultiply` as above), the codebase will transparently use the FPU - and everything is consistent.

But as soon as you employ TeX registers, things become different: Writing `\pgf@x=#1pt` means that the first argument is interpreted as a fixed point number in the range -16000...16000 (roughly). With `use fpu=true`, both is essentially violated: the fpu has neither fixed point numbers nor is it restricted to this data range. The error message arises because (at the point of this writing), floating point numbers are stored like `1Y1.0e1` where the `Y`
separates "flags" from mantissa. The `Y` is the first character where `\pgf@x=#1pt` bails out. Note, however, that the FPU is smart enough to detect if the RETURN VALUE of a custom function is a TeX register number or a float. But I am unaware of any way of asking "will the function handle floats?".

So, as already mentioned, `use fpu=false` disables the FPU; pgfplots will then operate with fixed point numbers in the range -16000...16000 and all the math functions should work.

The other solution is to use the basic layer math functions like `\pgfmathmultiply`. Note that unless I am mistaken, `\pgfmathmultiply` will also invoke `\pgfmathparse` (which is expensive). Use `\pgfmathmultiply@` to suppress argument parsing (which, however, needs a `\makeatletter` before defining the custom function).

Unfortunately, I am unaware of why the `\pgfmathand{} {}` solution fails. Does it work in PGF?

I hope this helps here.

Comment: Does setting `use fpu=false` disable floating point for all of the calculations?  Or just initially?  (Using floating point is desirable because it is more accurate, so it would be a shame to have to do everything without floating point calculations.)

Comment: Providing `use fpu=false` will disable the fpu for all computations. If I am not mistaken, it needs to be providing either in the document's preamble or for individual `\begin{axis}[use fpu=false]`. What precisely do you mean by "initially"? I agree that this is not desirable. However, if the provided data (for both, x and y) fits well into the data range of TeX, you may not notice any difference. For the more general case, a custom math function should rely on internal math functions like `\pgfmath<op>@`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this very simple code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{\edef\pgfmathresult{\ifdim#1pt<\z@0\else\ifdim#1pt>1pt 0\else1\fi\fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,color=gray] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
\draw[color=blue] plot (\x,{p(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you get this to work in `pgfplots`?  I like the way `pgfplots` lets you modify the axes and other plot properties easily.  I find plain `tikz` hard to work with.

Comment: The pgfmanual says your code begins with `\begingroup`and finishes with `\pgfmathreturn\pgf@x \endgroup` but it's not exactly the problem here. There is no problem inside pgf but the problem is with pgfplots. I think pgfplots uses only the functions until pgf 2.00 ( but it's my personal idea)

Answer (score 0):

I modified my answer with only an example from the pgfmanual (the first one for `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`.
This example from the pgfmanual  works with pgf and not with pgfplots (why ???)

The part with pgfplots gives
Latex Error: ./add_func_pgfplots.tex:77 Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{double}{1}{%
 \begingroup 
  \pgf@x=#1pt\relax 
  \multiply\pgf@x by2\relax 
  \pgfmathreturn\pgf@x
 \endgroup 
}
\makeatother 
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{double(44.3)}\pgfmathresult 

 \begin{tikzpicture} 
   \draw plot [domain=0:5, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{double(\x)}); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathdouble{1}
   \let\ra\pgfmathresult
   \draw (0,0) circle (\ra);% \ra is fine
 %  \begin{axis}
 %    \addplot[domain=-5:5, samples=50]{double(x)};
 %  \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this code works

```
 \documentclass{scrartcl}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

My pgf version is: \pgfversion 

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{double}{1}{
\begingroup
\pgfmathmultiply{#1}{#1} % instead of \pgfmathparse{#1*#1} from kristi
\endgroup 
} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
   \addplot[domain=-5:5, samples=50]{double(x)};
 \end{axis}   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The main problem with `\pgfmathparse` is the code is slow if we need to make a lot of loops

Answer (score 0):

@Altermundus  Thanks for that example code.  I tried using a shortened version for an example.  It seems like it works in `pgf`, but not in `pgfplots`.

Compiling this example code, I get

> My pgf version is: 2.10
>
> test(2.5) is 2

but no plot.  I get a bunch of errors at the `\addplot` line: "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" "Paragraph ended before \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat was complete"

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{test}{1}{%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmath@xa=#1pt\relax%
    \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfmath@xa)}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

My pgf version is: \pgfversion

test(2.5) is \pgfmathparse{test(2.5)}\pgfmathresult

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-2:2, samples=10]{test(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I added a new example very simple, The function is plotted with pgf and not with pgfplots and I don't know why . A great TeX expert perhaps have an answer.

Comment: I think you need to read the pgfplots manual. I never use this package (only to test some examples) perhaps there are some comments about the functions you can use !

Comment: I also try `declare function` with success in pgf and failure in pgfplots.

Comment: I try your function with `\draw plot [domain=0:5, samples=144, smooth] (\x,{test(\x)}); ` and it works in pgf