# Using ifthenelse in pgfmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, conditionals, pgfmath

Following questions on constructing functions on the forum, I tried to build some myself. I can't seem to get the `ifthenelse` function in TikZ/PGF to work. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

%this works
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{x^2}%
}

%this does not work
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{g}{0}{%
  \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(x<0,-x^2,x^2)}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,domain=-2:2,smooth}, 
  axis x line*=bottom, axis y line*=left, enlargelimits=upper] 

  \addplot {f};
  \addplot {g};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this code will compile.  Doesn't the second argument of `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` require a number?

Comment: You are correct. I added a 0 and now it behaves as I described (f works, g does not).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a problem with the `fpu` library that is used by pgfplots: The `ifthenelse` command is not implemented in `fpu`, so it falls back to the normal pgfmath routine, which then stumbles over the floating point format of the arguments, because numbers are handled in the form `1Y1.0e0]`.

To circumvent this, the `fpu` library can be disabled in the newly defined math function using

```
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
```

However, the x-value handed over by pgfplots is still in the floating point format, so it has to be converted into a fixed point format:

```
\pgfmathfloattofixed{\x}
\let\x=\pgfmathresult
```

In case the `fpu` library is not active, this will fail because `\pgfmathfloattofixed{\x}` doesn't know what to do with a fixed point number. So we need to use `\pgflibraryfpuifactive` to test whether `fpu` is active, and convert the number only if it is.

Now x is a normal fixed point number, and all the common pgfmath functions should work.

However, the pgfmath engine is less precise than `fpu`, so it might not be desirable to fall back to it.

As `ifthenelse` is not a very complicated function, we can just define it ourselves:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ifthenelsefpu}{3}{ %}
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#2 + !#1*#3} %
}
```

Which can be used like the original function.

I've put both approaches into the example document below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ifthenelsefpu}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#2 + !#1*#3}%
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{ifthenelsefpu(#1<0,#1^2,#1)}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{g}{1}{%
  \pgflibraryfpuifactive{%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{#1}%
    \let\x=\pgfmathresult%
  }%
  {%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}%
    \let\x=\pgfmathresult%
  }%
  \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\x<0,(\x)^2,\x)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[every axis plot post/.append style={
  mark=none,domain=-3:3,smooth}, 
  axis x line*=bottom, axis y line*=left, enlargelimits=upper]
  \addplot {f(x+0.5)};
  \addplot {g(x-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%Code for showing that the functions work outside pgfplots
\pgfmathf{-3}\pgfmathresult

\pgfmathg{-3}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots and ifthenelse]

Comment: @Jake : I understand the definition of f but not the definition of g

Comment: @Jake : I understand the definition of f but not the definition of g. `\pgfmathf{2} \pgfmathresult`   is fine but how do you use `\pgfmathg` ? Another question do you understand why with pgfplots there is a problem if we take the definition of ifthenelse as in pgf `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ifthenelsefpu}{3}{%
 \begingroup%
 \ifdim#1pt=0.0pt\relax% ....`

Comment: @Altermundus: As it was, the code for the `g` function only worked if the `fpu` library was active. I've fixed it now. The `\ifdim` approach doesn't work if the number is passed in floating point format (1Y1e0]), because there is a `Y` in the number, which `\ifdim` believes to be a strange unit. The number needs to be converted to a fixed point format (1.0) for that approach to work.

Comment: @Jake Thanks! if I understand but it's not sure, pgfplots adapts all the pgfmath functions or it uses only the functions defined by the fpu library ?

Comment: @Jake : Thank you very much. This answer my question completely.

Comment: @Altermundus: pgfplots activates the `fpu` library for floating point calculations. This library redefines most pgfmath functions, and pgfplots only uses those redefined functions.