# Change "<" to "<=" in pgfmath's and function

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I am using this method for [Defining a Piecewise Function for PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19510/defining-a-piecewise-function-for-pgfplots) and want to specifically define the function value at the endpoint to be 1, not 0. When I change the `<` in the `and` to `<=` I get **Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)**

This MWE [produces this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yak4q.png) but should have the black circle at `(1,1)` when it works properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\pLabel}{
$p(x)=
\begin{cases}
    x & 0 < x {\textcolor{red}{{}\leq{}}} 1\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
}
\tikzstyle{MyStyle}=[domain=-0.5:1.5, samples=100, ultra thick,blue]
\tikzstyle{pLabelStyle}=[above, yshift=25ex, xshift=-28ex]


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1)*#1)}% This compiles with the "<"
  %\pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<=1)*#1)}% This is what I want: note the "<="
}

% Compute point of interest
\newcommand*{\XValue}{1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\QatXValue}{p(\XValue)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle]{p(x)} node [pLabelStyle] {\pLabel};
    \fill (axis cs: \XValue,\QatXValue)  circle (4pt)
        node [right, yshift=1.0ex] {$(1,p(1))$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a simple fix?

Comment: I'm not a heavy `pgfmath` user (used it once), but did you try using ">" and "not"?  (I know, I know, this is trivial, but maybe this helps...?)

Comment: @mbork: I did not think to try that, but it appears that the solution was pretty much along those lines. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is similar to the one described in [Using ifthenelse in pgfmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/using-ifthenelse-in-pgfmath): It's an issue with the fpu library. As a workaround, you can define a new function that just negates the `less` function. You can assign this new function to an operator, e.g. `!>` for "not greater" (which is the same as "less or equal"):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\pLabel}{
$p(x)=
\begin{cases}
    x & 0 < x {\textcolor{red}{{}\leq{}}} 1\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
}
\tikzstyle{MyStyle}=[domain=-0.5:1.5, samples=100, ultra thick,blue]
\tikzstyle{pLabelStyle}=[above, yshift=25ex, xshift=-28ex]

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{floatnotgreater}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{!(#1>#2)}%
}

\pgfmathdeclareoperator{!>}{floatnotgreater}{2}{infix} {250}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1!>1)*#1)}%
}

% Compute point of interest
\newcommand*{\XValue}{1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\QatXValue}{p(\XValue)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle]{p(x)} node [pLabelStyle] {\pLabel};
    \fill (axis cs: \XValue,\QatXValue)  circle (4pt)
        node [right, yshift=1.0ex] {$(1,p(1))$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great. One minor correction: The `\pgfmathparse` line requires a trailing `%` (at least with TexLive 2010)

Comment: You're right, I missed the `%` when I cleaned up the code and removed the comment line. Fixed now.