# pgfplots and ifthenelse

Tags: pgfplots

To be honest, the following example not exactly works as I had expected.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/using-ifthenelse-in-pgfmath
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ifthenelsefpu}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#2 + !#1*#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
  ]
    \addplot3[
      surf,
      samples = 20,
      domain = -1:1,
      y domain = -1:1,
    ] ({x}, {y}, {ifthenelsefpu({(x==0) && (y==0)},1,0)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result should be single peak at (0,0), but ...

[here should be a picture, but at the moment the upload is not working for me - sorry]

Comment: If you have the picture somewhere we can add it for you. :)

Comment: Thanks, but from this pc i can not upload anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `20` samples in each direction the sample points in the interval from `-1` to `1` miss the value `0`.  Changing to `21` samples gives

[image: Sample output]

It is perhaps easiest to think about the case of `2` samples, these are `-1` and `1` vs.  `3` samples, which are `-1`,`0` and `1`.  In the `20` sample case, first sample is `-1` and the other are spaced `2/19` apart, so the list of values is

```
-1, -17/19, -15/19, -13/19, -11/19, -9/19, -7/19, -5/19, -3/19, -1/19
```

and the corresponding positive values.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
% taken from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/using-ifthenelse-in-pgfmath
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ifthenelsefpu}{3}{%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*#2 + !#1*#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
  ]
    \addplot3[
      surf,
      samples = 21,
      domain = -1:1,
      y domain = -1:1,
    ] ({x}, {y}, {ifthenelsefpu({(x==0) && (y==0)},1,0)});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. But this was not my problem and it does not change it, alas. Let me describe the resulting picture: Not only the value at (0,0) equals 1 but all the values for (x<0,y<0)! So the complete quadrant is "high". Maybe this is due to an old version of pgfplots (1.10)? I think I should update ...

Comment: The above is produced with `pgfplots` version `1.12`.  So I suggest you update.

Comment: Yes! That was exactly the cause, thanks for the hint.