# Defining a Piecewise Function for PGFplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to define a piecewise function `q(x)`, and attempted to adapt the solution to [this question on using pgfmathdeclarefunction to create a unit pulse function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-do-i-use-pgfmathdeclarefunction-to-create-define-a-new-pgf-function), and this works fine. However, when I attempt to plot `q(x+4)+0.5`, the resulting graph is not what I would expect. However, applying the same transformation on the unit pulse function from the above mentioned link works fine.

So, is there a better way to define a piecewise defined function?

The MWE below produces the following result.

[image]

Note that the graphs on the left are as one would expect for both `p(x)` and `p(x+4)+0.5`. The graphs on the right are correct for `q(x)`, but but incorrect for `q(x+4)+0.5`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\pLabel}{
$p(x)=
\begin{cases}
    1 & 0 < x < 1\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
}
\newcommand{\qLabel}{
$q(x)=
\begin{cases}
    x & 0 < x < 1\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
}

\newcommand{\pShiftedLabel}{$p(x+4)+0.5$}
\newcommand{\qShiftedLabel}{$q(x+4)+0.5$}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1))}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{q}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1)*x)}%
}

\tikzstyle{MyStyle}=[domain=-5:5, samples=50, ultra thick]
\tikzstyle{pLabelStyle}=[above, yshift=22ex, xshift=-10ex]
\tikzstyle{qLabelStyle}=[below, yshift=-2ex, xshift=-10ex]
\tikzstyle{ShiftedLabelStyle}=[above left, xshift=1ex]


\begin{document}
%------------------ Using \pgfmathdeclarefunction -----------
Plot of $p(x)$ and \pShiftedLabel using PGF Version \pgfversion, followed by a plot of $q(x)$ and \qShiftedLabel

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{p(x)} node [pLabelStyle] {\pLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{p(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\pShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{q(x)} node [qLabelStyle] {\qLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{q(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\qShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% --------------------- Using "declare function" -------------
Using declare function to define localp(x) and localq(x):

\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={localp(\t) =  and(\t > 0, \t < 1);}]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{localp(x)}  node [pLabelStyle] {\pLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{localp(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\pShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={localq(\t) = (and(\t > 0, \t < 1)*x);}]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{localq(x)} node [qLabelStyle] {\qLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{localq(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\qShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both methods for defining piecewise functions are fine, but you should use

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{q}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1)*#1)}%
}
```

instead of `and(#1>0, #1<1)*x)`, and

```
[declare function={localq(\t) = (and(\t > 0, \t < 1)*\t);}]
```

instead of `[declare function={localq(\t) = (and(\t > 0, \t < 1)*x);}]`, because you don't actually want the function value to be `x`, but rather the value of the argument (`x+4` in this case).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\pLabel}{
$p(x)=
\begin{cases}
    1 & 0 < x < 1\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
}
\newcommand{\qLabel}{
$q(x)=
\begin{cases}
    x & 0 < x < 1\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
}

\newcommand{\pShiftedLabel}{$p(x+4)+0.5$}
\newcommand{\qShiftedLabel}{$q(x+4)+0.5$}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1))}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{q}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1)*#1)}%
}

\tikzstyle{MyStyle}=[domain=-5:5, samples=100, ultra thick]
\tikzstyle{pLabelStyle}=[above, yshift=22ex, xshift=-10ex]
\tikzstyle{qLabelStyle}=[below, yshift=-2ex, xshift=-10ex]
\tikzstyle{ShiftedLabelStyle}=[above left, xshift=1ex]


\begin{document}
%------------------ Using \pgfmathdeclarefunction -----------
Plot of $p(x)$ and \pShiftedLabel using PGF Version \pgfversion, followed by a plot of $q(x)$ and \qShiftedLabel

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{p(x)} node [pLabelStyle] {\pLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{p(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\pShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{q(x)} node [qLabelStyle] {\qLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{q(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\qShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% --------------------- Using "declare function" -------------
Using declare function to define localp(x) and localq(x):

\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={localp(\t) =  and(\t > 0, \t < 1);}]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{localp(x)}  node [pLabelStyle] {\pLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{localp(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\pShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={localq(\t) = (and(\t > 0, \t < 1)*\t);}]
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[MyStyle, blue]{localq(x)} node [qLabelStyle] {\qLabel};
    \addplot[MyStyle, red]{localq(x+4)+0.5} node [ShiftedLabelStyle] {\qShiftedLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: piecewise pgfplots functions]

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I ever would have realized my mistake. The problem came about as I had defined `\newcommand{\PieceA}{x}` and was using that in my original code (I eliminated that for the MWE). So I would have to use `\pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1)*\PieceA)}`. Is there a simple way to change definition of `\PieceA` to get this to work. I tried the `##1` trick that is used when a `newcommand` is defined within `newcommand`, but that didn't work.

Comment: @Peter: Not that I know of. I tried `\edef\PieceA{\noexpand#1}`, but that doesn't work. This should probably go into a new question, I'm sure there are some TeX cracks who know what to do.

Comment: @Peter I admit that I do not see the bigger picture - it appears as if you really need the macro expansion. Does it help if you make `\PieceA` dependent on the variable, i.e. `\newcommands{\PieceA}[1]{#1}`? This would allow you to replace `\PieceA` by some expression like `\newcommand{\PieceA}[1]{(#1+4)}` AND it would fix your problem because you could write `...#1<1)*\PieceA{#1})}`. But its just guessing.

Comment: @Christian: Sorry, we should have linked to the follow-up question and answer: [How to define a parameterized command to be consumable in \pgfmathdeclarefunction?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19516/2552)

Comment: @Jake thanks for the note - I see. By the way: you have collected a huge bulk of experience with pgfplots. Let me know if you have interest in modifying the pgfplots codebase or in to adding new features!