# How to define a parameterized command to be consumable in \pgfmathdeclarefunction?

Tags: macros, pgfplots

This is the solution to [defining a piecewise function for pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19510/defining-a-piecewise-function-for-pgfplots/19513#19513).

However, I would like to be able to use a macro to define each of the pieces of the function.  It is simple to do this if one is using a local `declare function` as shown in the MWE below which uses `\LocalPieceA` and `\LocalPieceB` as the definition of what the function does in the two separate domains.

But, how do I do modify `\PieceA` and `\PieceB` so that I can use them in the `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`?  I attempted to use the `##` trick that works when defining macros within macros that need to access the parameters of the outer macro, and Jake tried the `\edef\PieceA{\noexpand#1}` in the above referenced question and that too did not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\rLabel}{
$r(x)=
\begin{cases}
    x & 0 < x < 1\\
   -x+2 & 1 < x < 2\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$
}

% Want to be able to use \PieceA and \PieceB in the \pgfmathdeclarefunction instead 
% of (#1) and (-#1+2).  With [declare function], this is easy as shown below
\newcommand{\PieceA}{(##1)}
\newcommand{\PieceB}{(-##1+2)}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{q}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{((and(#1>0, #1<1)*#1)+(and(#1>1, #1<4)*(-#1+2)))}%
}

\tikzstyle{MyPlotStyle}=[domain=-5:5, samples=50, ultra thick]
\tikzstyle{rLabelStyle}=[above, yshift=-15ex, xshift=-25ex]

\begin{document}
%------------------ Using \pgfmathdeclarefunction -----------
Plot of $r(x)$ using PGF Version \pgfversion.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[clip=false]
    \addplot[MyPlotStyle, red]{q(x)} node [rLabelStyle] {\rLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% --------------------- Using "declare function" -------------
Using declare function to define localp(x) and localq(x):

\newcommand{\LocalPieceA}{(\x)}% These two works great!!
\newcommand{\LocalPieceB}{(-\x+2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[declare function={localr(\x) =  and(\x > 0, \x < 1)*\LocalPieceA+and(\x > 1, \x < 4)*\LocalPieceB;}]
  \begin{axis}[clip=false]
    \addplot[MyPlotStyle, blue]{localr(x)}  node [rLabelStyle] {\rLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you define a command inside another command, `#1` refers to the first parameter of the outer command and `##1` refers to the first parameter of the inner command. `#1` is accessible in both the outer and inner commands, but `##1` is only accessible inside the inner command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
\newcommand{\PieceA}[1]{(#1)}
\newcommand{\PieceB}[1]{(-#1+2)}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{q}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{((and(#1>0, #1<1)*\PieceA{#1})+(and(#1>1, #1<4)*\PieceB{#1}))}%
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. Only excuse I have is that it was late when I had this problem :-)

Comment: @Peter: If you don't define a nested command, no reason to use `##1`.