# Using PGFPlots to plot macro result

Tags: pgfplots

I've got a few macros that perform floating point lookups and calculations for me and I'm interesting in plotting their results. They're the kind of calculation which requires if/else, so they can't be easily written as a simple math formula for `\addplot`.  I've been able to plot the results using a `\foreach`, but only by having a separate `\addplot` for each point in the series:

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,100}{
  \edef\temp{\noexpand \addplot coordinates{ (\x,\myMacro{\x}) }; }
  \temp
}
```

Granted, I'm sure that I could force it to *look* like one data series, but that seems like a very inelegant solution. Is it possible to define a data series where y values are provided by a LaTeX macro?  Something like

```
\addplot{
   \coordinates{
     foreach \x in {1,...,100){
       (\x,\myMacro{\x})
     }
   }
};
```

or

```
\addplot[variableICanPassToMacro=\x, domain=1:100] ({\x},{\myMacro{\x}});
```

?

Comment: You should be able use `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`. An example of which is at [How to define a parameterized command to be consumable in \pgfmathdeclarefunction?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19516/4301). If you provide an actual macro that computes the results that you desire it would be easier to give you a more detailed answer.  Ideally, it would be best if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you please make it a full working example starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `...\end{document}`? It helps solvers a lot to start working on it.

Comment: \pgfmathdeclarefunction is the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: I created a MWE, but my question has changed a fair bit now that I know about `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`, so I think it's more appropriate to post it as a new one.  The new question is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171263/plotting-a-function-defined-with-pgfmathdeclarefunction