# Declaring sinc in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I am trying to declare the `sinc`-function for usage in `tikz`. I tried two different ways:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzmath{
        function sincm(\x) {
            if abs(\x) < 0.001 then {
                return 1.0;
            } else {
                return sin(\x r)/\x;
            };
        };
    }
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{%
            abs(#1)<0.001 ? 1 : sin(#1 r)/#1%
            }%
        }

    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[domain=0:0.5, samples=1000] plot (\x, {sincm(\x*20)});
    \draw[domain=0:0.5, samples=1000, red, dotted] plot (\x,{sinc(\x*20)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both ways yield the same result. I would like to use `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` variante, first of all to be able to declare this function globally, maybe even for several `tikz`-pictures. However, if I set the start of the plotting domain to zero:

```
\draw[domain=0:0.5, samples=1000, red, dotted] plot (\x,{sinc(\x*20)});
```

I get the Error `Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide '0,0' by '0.0'`. Somehow, in this case, the `ifthenelse`-structure in my declaration of `sinc` does not seem to work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, when encountered with an if-then syntax, PGF evaluates both branches and then chooses hence it will divide no matter what the value of #1 is. Instead you can use it to branch off

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{abs(#1)<0.01 ? int(1) : int(0)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult>0 \pgfmathparse{1}\else\pgfmathparse{sin(#1 r)/#1}\fi%
        }

    \draw (-1,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[domain=0:0.5, samples=250] plot (\x,{sinc(20*\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! This is a very counter-intuitive behavior, i would have thought such thing should be documented in the pgf-manual...

Comment: @Dux I'm guessing that it is more pragmatic this way due to TeX way of doing things. Note that you have to parse first and act later in TeX which brings in its own strangeness.

Comment: @percusse Where does exactly that “parse first and act later” behaviour come from?

Comment: @Manuel Things like collecting expressions without evaluating them for possible macros inside it. Short circuiting is way more tedious than merely processing the expressions and choosing between `#2` and `#3`. It is possible of course but it is what it is. And again I'm pretty much putting words in TikZ developers' mouths.

Comment: Does anyone know whether this function will find its way into the code of the fine pgf package?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when I needed to plot a sinc function with `pgfplots`. It took me a while to figure out that the accepted answer for the original question here does not work in that case because of the way `pgfplots` handles numbers (see for example [Plotting a function defined with \pgfmathdeclarefunction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171263/plotting-a-function-defined-with-pgfmathdeclarefunction)).

So in case anybody needs it, here is a solution that works both with TikZ `\draw plot` and `\addplot`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{sinc}{1}{%
        \pgfmathparse{(#1==0 ? 1: sin(#1 r))/(#1==0 ? 1: #1)}%
        }
    
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot+[no markers] {sinc(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

EDIT: I improved my answer following @user202729's comment.

Comment: The cause is indeed correct, but the fix seems incorrect...

Comment: The bug is actually covered here [tikz pgf - `Missing = inserted for \ifnum` when using addplot - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262537/missing-inserted-for-ifnum-when-using-addplot) . Answers there doesn't seem better either...

Comment: Why do you consider the fix to be incorrect? When I compile my code, the result looks right.

Comment: Explained in my answer → https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666170/250119. Your answer is incorrect for the same reason why Heiko Oberdiek's answer is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I would not have answered here had I seen your detailed answer beforehand...

Comment: I mean I only write that answer after noticing your answer here anyway, so in some sense it helps.

Comment: Good job! For sinc(x)=sin(πx)/(πx), use `\pgfmathparse{(#1==0 ? 1: sin(pi*#1 r))/(#1==0 ? 1: pi*#1)}%` instead.