# pgf-tikz problem with 'declare function'

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I need to make a plot of a non-linear functions. To get familiar with the 'declare function' capability of `pgf-tikz`, I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.0,
      declare function={
        func(\x,\a) = 1.0/(\x^\a);
      }]
% draw grid  
      \draw[very thin,color=gray] (0.0,0.0) grid (2.0,2.0); 
% draw axes 
      \draw[->] (0.0,0.0) -- (2.0,0.0) node[right] {$x$};
      \draw[->] (0.0,0.0) -- (0.0,2.0) node[above] {$y$};     
% draw functions
      \draw[blue]  plot[domain=0.5:2.0,samples=100] (\x,{func(\x,1.0)});
      \draw[red]   plot[domain=0.8:2.0,samples=100] (\x,{func(\x,2.0)}); 
      \draw[green] plot[domain=0.5:2.0,samples=100] (\x,{func(\x,0.5)}); 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So what I expect to see are three lines corresponding to `1/x`, `1/x^2`, and `1/sqrt(x)`.  The last function call did not give the correct function. Since I'm new to using the math functionality of `pgf-tikz`, I suspect I'm doing something wrong or I'm overlooking something. I'd be glad to get some pointers that

- help me fix this problem; and
- get some advice about how to best/better approach this problem.

The function I will need to plot is going to be more complicated, but also smooth and under some limits approaches `1/x`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: As far as your second question you should see this question on [consistently specifying a function and use it for computation and plotting)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/consistently-specify-a-function-and-use-it-for-computation-and-plotting)

Comment: Thanks for the useful link. This cleared up a lot of things for me.

Answer (score 8):

### `TikZ` Solution:

I believe there are some limitations in using the internal math engine with power type functions (but for some reason works just fine with `pgfplots` as in the solution below), but if you change your definition from `func(\x,\a) = 1.0/(\x^\a)` to:

```
func(\t,\a) = 1.0/(exp((\a)*ln(\t)));
```

you get (and also added `very thick` option to `\draw`):

[image]

---

##`Pgfplots` Solution:

However, I would recommend that you use `pgfplots` for graphing.  As per [Consistently specify a Function and use it for computation and plotting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/consistently-specify-a-function-and-use-it-for-computation-and-plotting), I would recommend that you use the approach suggest there to define the function:

```
\def\func(#1,#2){1.0/((#1)^(#2))}
```

This method will allow you to be able to use this one definition for:

1. Computation of values to:

- Define a piecewise function as in [Defining a Piecewise Function for PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19510/defining-a-piecewise-function-for-pgfplots),
- Compute values of individual points as in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/consistently-specify-a-function-and-use-it-for-computation-and-plotting) where I label a specific point given the x value
- be able to use it as any other built in math function and define a translation as in [the green curve](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33602/consistently-specify-a-function-and-use-it-for-computation-and-plotting)

2. Graphing using pgfplot
3. Graphing using pgfplots/gnuplot

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\func(#1,#2){1.0/((#1)^(#2))}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0.5:2.0, samples=100,
    every axis plot post/.style= ultra thick]
    \addplot [blue] {\func(x,1.0)};%
    \addplot [red]  {\func(x,2.0)};%
    \addplot [green]{\func(x,0.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem with the `exp` function from `TikZ`, it is solved in the CVS version. Alternatively, you can use the code Jake provides here: [Is plotting exponential graphs a known source of bugs in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/is-plotting-exponential-graphs-a-known-source-of-bugs-in-tikz/31791#31791) in the preamble to solve the problem.