# What is the clearest way to graph a piecewise function?

Tags: pgfplots, pstricks, graphs

I have a function defined as:

[image]

How can I graph that using functions instead of coordinates? I'm currently working with pgfplots but I'm open to something else if it's better.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your function

[image]

has 3 discontinuity points which are at `t=0`, `t=1`, and `t=2`. The following graph is correct from mathematics point of view.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=yellow,opacity=0.5](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(3.5,1.5)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
    \psplot[arrows=-o]{-2.5}{-1}{0}
    \psset{arrows=*-o}
    \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
    \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
    \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
    \psplot[arrows=*-]{2}{3.5}{1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Edit 3

It is easy to join the discontinuity points with vertical lines even though it must be avoided because the graph will no longer tell us about a function.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=yellow,opacity=0.5](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(3.5,1.5)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
    \pscustom
    {
        \psplot{-2.5}{-1}{0}
        \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
        \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
        \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
        \psplot{2}{3.5}{1}
    }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Edit 3.1

I forgot to tell you that you need to compile it (to get a tight PDF image) with either `xelatex` or a sequence of `latex` followed by `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf`.

Import the PDF image from within your input file by using `\includegraphics` and compile the main input file with `pdflatex`. I guessed your scenario like this.

### Edit 3.14

I added some macros to the preamble for adjusting the size of canvas and borders.
Hopefully it is useful for you.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

% to adjust the unit
\psset
{
    xunit=1cm,
    yunit=3cm,
}


% to adjust the axes
\def\L{-2.5}
\def\R{3.5}
\def\B{-0.2}
\def\T{1.2}


% to adjust the borders
\def\dL{2pt}
\def\dR{12pt}
\def\dB{2pt}
\def\dT{18pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false]
        (\dimexpr\L\psxunit-\dL\relax,\dimexpr\B\psyunit-\dB\relax)
        (\dimexpr\R\psxunit+\dR\relax,\dimexpr\T\psyunit+\dT\relax)

    %comment the following \psframe* if you DON'T need a colored background.

    \psframe*[linecolor=blue,opacity=0.1]
        (\dimexpr\L\psxunit-\dL\relax,\dimexpr\B\psyunit-\dB\relax)
        (\dimexpr\R\psxunit+\dR\relax,\dimexpr\T\psyunit+\dT\relax)

        \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(\L,\B)(\R,\T)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
        \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
        \psplot[arrows=-o]{\L}{-1}{0}
        \psset{arrows=*-o}
        \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
        \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
        \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
        \psplot[arrows=*-]{2}{\R}{1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

### Edit 3.141

I just realized there is a bad feature at each hollow dot when using the default value of `plotpoints` (which is `20`). Fortunately, your functions have low frequencies, so I can reduce `plotpoints` to `2` without side effects to hide the bad feature.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

% to adjust the unit
\psset
{
    xunit=1cm,
    yunit=3cm,
}


% to adjust the axes
\def\L{-2.5}
\def\R{3.5}
\def\B{-0.2}
\def\T{1.2}


% to adjust the borders
\def\dL{2pt}
\def\dR{12pt}
\def\dB{2pt}
\def\dT{18pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false]
    (\dimexpr\L\psxunit-\dL\relax,\dimexpr\B\psyunit-\dB\relax)
    (\dimexpr\R\psxunit+\dR\relax,\dimexpr\T\psyunit+\dT\relax)

    %comment the following \psframe* if you DON'T need a colored background.
    %\psframe*[linecolor=blue,opacity=0.1]
    %(\dimexpr\L\psxunit-\dL\relax,\dimexpr\B\psyunit-\dB\relax)
    %(\dimexpr\R\psxunit+\dR\relax,\dimexpr\T\psyunit+\dT\relax)

    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(\L,\B)(\R,\T)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red,plotpoints=2}
    \psplot[arrows=-o]{\L}{-1}{0}
    \psset{arrows=*-o}
    \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
    \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
    \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
    \psplot[arrows=*-]{2}{\R}{1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

If your functions have high frequency then decreasing `plotpoints` makes the plots no longer smooth. To avoid this side effect, we have to increase `plotpoints` and override the hollow dots with solid circles.

Comment: Also, thanks for the response. The first graph looks perfect! I definitely want it to be disconnected.

Comment: Looks perfect. I am actually just going with the version from before Edit ~Pi :)
It looked fine to me, but I'll probably use the macros on future graphs.

Comment: You created a lot of very good PSTricks examples. Would you like the idea of a PSTricks gallery in the very same shape as the [TikZ gallery](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/)? I could setup a server with the same structure (based on PostgreSQL and Django) but exclusively for PSTricks. Would be a nice showcase and useful for new users. I could care for gallery maintainance and feeding in content, which is sent to me by email or taken from here.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: A nice idea. I will participate in such a idea. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 46):

If you are using `pgfplots` you can use `pgfmathdeclarefunction` to specify the function and then use it the same way you would just a built in function. You can then plot is all at once if you want the end points connected, or plot each section separately:

[image]

### References:

- [Defining a Piecewise Function for PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19510/defining-a-piecewise-function-for-pgfplots)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*{\PhM}{\phantom{-}}%

\newcommand{\pLabel}{%
$F(t) = \begin{cases}
  0                     & \PhM t < -1 \\[0.8ex]
  \frac{1}{4}t+\frac{1}{4}  & -1\le t <0 \\[0.8ex]
  \frac{1}{2}           & \PhM 0\le t <1\\[0.8ex]
  \frac{1}{12}t+\frac{7}{12} & \PhM 1\le t <2\\[0.8ex]
  1                     & \PhM t\ge 2
\end{cases}
$
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{PieceA}{1}{(0)}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{PieceB}{1}{(#1/4 + 1/4)}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{PieceC}{1}{(0.5)}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{PieceD}{1}{(#1/12 + 7/12)}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{PieceE}{1}{(1)}%


\pgfmathdeclarefunction{MyFunction}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{%
    (and(   1,    #1<-1)*(0)            +%
    (and(#1>=-1,  #1< 0)*(#1/4 + 1/4)   +%
    (and(#1>= 0,  #1< 1)*(0.5)          +%
    (and(#1>= 1,  #1< 2)*(#1/12 + 7/12) +%
    (and(#1>= 2,    1  )*(1)%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=-5:5, blue, samples=100, ultra thick] {MyFunction(x)};
    \node [right] at (axis cs: -5.5,0.7) {\tiny\pLabel};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \foreach \xStart/\xEnd  in {-5/-1, -1/0, 0/1, 1/2, 2/5} {
        \addplot[domain=\xStart:\xEnd, blue, samples=10, ultra thick] {MyFunction(x)};
    }
    \node [right] at (axis cs: -5.5,0.7) {\tiny\pLabel};% Labe graph

    % Show discontinuty points
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: 0, 0.250) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue,  thick] (axis cs: 0, 0.500) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: 1, 0.500) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs: 1, 0.666) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: 2, 0.750) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs: 2, 1.000) circle (2.0pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Be careful, the function has 3 discontinuities, at `t=0`, `t=1`, and `t=2`.

Comment: In mathematics, we don't draw  vertical lines at discontinuity points because those lines will make the "function" is no longer a function.

Comment: That code is causing an error for me on the \addplot line.

Comment: @Dash: Please ensure you are using the latest released version of `pgfplots`. I am using the latest TeXLive2011.

Comment: To interrupt the line at the discontinuities, I would use a `\foreach` loop that invokes a separate `\addplot` for each segment:

`\foreach \min/\max/\function in {-10 / -1 / 0, -1 / 0 / {1/4*x+1/4}, 0 / 1 / 0.5, 1 / 2 / {1/12*x+7/12}, 2 / 10 / 1}{ \addplot [blue, ultra thick] [domain=\min:\max]{\function};}`

Comment: @Jake: As I said before you are just too fast -- just figured it out then saw your comment... Thanks again..

Comment: A hollow dot or solid dot is also important to clarify exactly whether or not the segment end point is undefined at the discontinuity point in question.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Good point. Have added that as well.

Comment: +1 I like this. For the hollow/solid dots you can use `\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*}}
\pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=blue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}` in the preamble, and then     `\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0.25)(1,0.5)(2,0.75)};
    \addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,0.5)(1,0.666)(2,1)};` in the picture