# Plot function with discontinuity

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I apologize if this question is similar to this one [Plot non-continuous function with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76418/plot-non-continuous-function-with-tikz). In fact, in order to plot the  following function between $-5$ and $+5$, by highlighting the $ (0, -2) $, $ ($ 1.1) and $ (2.1) $ discontinuity points:

```
\begin{align}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x &     if \ x\in]-\infty,0[,  \\
x-2&   if \ x\in[0,1[, \\
1&       if \ x\in[1,2],  \\
\dfrac{1}{x-2}&  if \ x\in]2,+\infty[.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
```

I mimic this [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76418/plot-non-continuous-function-with-tikz).  Unfortunately, I get an error.

```
NOTE: coordinate (1Y2.0e0],4Y0.0e0]) has been dropped because it is unbounded (
in y). (see also unbounded coords=jump). 
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 22.

! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.22 \end{axis}
```

I wonder if it is possible de draw the graph of this function by using the TiKz package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*}} \pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=blue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-5:0,blue] {x};
\addplot[domain=0:1,blue] {x-2};
\addplot[domain=1:2,blue] {1};
\addplot[domain=2:5, blue]{1/(x-2)}
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:4,16) -- (axis cs:4,4);
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:6,6) -- (axis cs:6,-5);
\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)(-1,-1)(6,-5)};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,-2)(1,1)(1,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank for reading.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Not everyone is at a pc, so it might be a good idea to cite the error.

Comment: Btw the error is presumably the dfrac which should be written as just `1/(x-2)`

Comment: Holdot and soldot look familiar :) I reckon @daleif's comment should fix it

Comment: I'm working on it… it's not only that…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, the error were two: you missed a semicolon and you got the `\dfrac` command wrong, and the same line missed a `;`

Apart from the `;` the `\dfrac` command is a math mode command which tells to `LaTeX` to typeset a fraction, like it was in display mode even if it's inline.

Here you don't want to typeset a fraction, but to specify a function value, so no typesetting command are required

So it would become: `\addplot[domain=2:5, blue]{1/(x-2)};` as suggested by @Daleif.

Also to write your curve you should be able to understand the command usages. I will try and summarize them, just in case:

- `addplot` simply tells `tikz` to draw the specific instruction. The `domain` parameter specifies the domain of the specific (part) of the plot, and it receives the function to draw. When used in the bottom two instructions, it tells to add to draw the object `soldot` and `holdot` at the specific coordinates
- `soldot` and `holdot` are defined to represent solid and hollow dots respectively.
- The other `\draw` commands connect the discontinuity points to one another.

If you understand that, to draw your plot is simply a matter of adjusting the parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*}} \pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=blue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-5:0,blue] {x};
\addplot[domain=0:1,blue] {x-2};
\addplot[domain=1:2,blue] {1};
\addplot[domain=2:5, blue]{1/(x-2)};
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:0,-2);
\draw[dotted] (axis cs:1,-1) -- (axis cs:1,1);
\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)(1,-1)};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,-2)(1,1)(2,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With result:

[image]

Comment: I am very grateful for cherished aid. By the way, give some advice to give a suitable label axis and grid graph?

Comment: @Zbigniew you mean something like `\begin{axis}[xlabel=x,ylabel=y]` to label them? I don't understand about the grid, but I think it's outside the question scope: you'd better search through the website to find a solution that suites you or, **way better** try browsing through `tikz` documentation going specifically for what you need

Comment: @Zbigniew don't thank me, you know the rules! :P