# Line is drawn below x-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want the line to be drawn above the x-axis. Now the line is drawn first and then the x-axis is plotted. I want to reverse it.

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = \(t\),
            ylabel = {\(\text{Hv}(t)\)},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1.5,
            every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
            tick align=inside
        ]

        \addplot [
            domain=0:5, 
            samples=100, 
            color=red,
        ]
        {1};

        \addplot [
            domain=-5:0, 
            samples=100, 
            color=red,
        ]
        {0};
        \addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,1)};
        \addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: Line is drawn below the x-axis]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Next time, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), like the one used by @Jinwen in their answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the axes in `pgfplots` [are normally drawn below the plot traces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483585/pgfplots-axis-on-top-will-cross-out-ybar-value-nodes).

Your problem is brought by the clipping behavior: all plots are clipped to the coordinate areas by default.

If you look closely:

[image: line at 1]

[image: line at 0]

in the horizontal axis, you have the line clipped at y=0; so its thickness is half than expected and you also see half of the line of the axes (which is centered on y=0 too).

You can solve that by using `clip=false` in the option of the `axis` environment, but, if you want more fine-grained control over clipping, you can do like this (thanks to [@Jinwen answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/645733/38080) for the MWE):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=red,only marks,mark=*}} \pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = \(t\),
            ylabel = {\(\text{Hv}(t)\)},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=1.5,
            every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
            tick align=inside,
            clip mode = individual,
        ]

        \addplot [
            domain=0:5,
            samples=100,
            color=red,
        ]
        {1};

        \addplot [
            domain=-5:0,
            samples=100,
            color=red,
            clip = false,
        ]
        {0};
        \addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,1)};
        \addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make the axis invisible by setting `ymin` to be a small negative value (e.g. `-0.01`). (I don't know your `soldot` and `holdot` styles, below is my guess based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362774).)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=red,only marks,mark=*}} \pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=red,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = \(t\),
            ylabel = {\(\text{Hv}(t)\)},
            ymin=-.01,
            ymax=1.5,
            every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
            tick align=inside
        ]

        \addplot [
            domain=0:5,
            samples=100,
            color=red,
        ]
        {1};

        \addplot [
            domain=-5:0,
            samples=100,
            color=red,
        ]
        {0};
        \addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,1)};
        \addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]