# Scientific workplace piecewise constant function

Tags: graphs

I want to sketch a piecewise constant function. Ie S(t) on y axis, time on x axis. The values of S(t) are arbitrary, I just want a piecewise constant function with time partition 1/10 to use:

> S(t)=10 for 0≤t<1/10
>
> S(t)=3 for 1/10≤t<2/10
>
> and so forth up to t=1.

I want to have a closed circle at the left endpoint and an open one at the right endpoint to indicate the discontinuity, ie open circle at t=0, closed circle at t=1/10 for S(t)=10,and a line connecting the two points, open circle at t=1/10 for S(t)=3 open cicle at t=2/10 and so forth. I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please have a look at [What is the clearest way to graph a piecewise function?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/what-is-the-clearest-way-to-graph-a-piecewise-function/), and let us know if that provides a solution for you.  If you can not get exactly what you want with the answers provided there, please post what you have so far and then others here can help you with a specific issue with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option using [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*}} \pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=blue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$S(t)$]
\foreach \start/\value [evaluate=\start as \end using \start+0.1] 
  in {0/10,0.1/3,0.2/5,0.3/0,0.4/2,0.5/-3,0.6/4,0.7/5,0.8/1,0.9/-1}
\addplot[domain=\start:\end,blue] {\value};
\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0,10)(0.1,3)(0.2,5)(0.3,0)(0.4,2)(0.5,-3)(0.6,4)(0.7,5)(0.8,1)(0.9,-1)};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0.1,10)(0.2,3)(0.3,5)(0.4,0)(0.5,2)(0.6,-3)(0.7,4)(0.8,5)(0.9,1)(1,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A change requested in a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\pgfplotsset{soldot/.style={color=blue,only marks,mark=*}} \pgfplotsset{holdot/.style={color=blue,fill=white,only marks,mark=*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$S(t)$]
\foreach \start/\value [evaluate=\start as \end using \start+0.1] 
  in {0/10,0.1/3,0.2/5,0.3/0,0.4/2,0.5/-3,0.6/4,0.7/5,0.8/1,0.9/-1}
\addplot[domain=\start:\end,blue] {\value};
\addplot[soldot] coordinates{(0,10)(0.1,3)(0.2,5)(0.3,0)(0.4,2)(0.5,-3)(0.6,4)(0.7,5)(0.8,1)(0.9,-1)};
\addplot[holdot] coordinates{(0.1,10)(0.2,3)(0.3,5)(0.4,0)(0.5,2)(0.6,-3)(0.7,4)(0.8,5)(0.9,1)(1,-1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can i change closed end point to left and open circle to right?

Comment: @LochlanBoils You're welcome. Regarding your question, interchange `soldot` and `holdot` in my example code. Also, don't forget to accept (different from up-voting) the answer that you consider solved best your problem; in case of doubt, see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: I changed it but am having a problem with texnicentre which i just reinstalled, it wont compile pdf, keep getting error that the file could not be found, presume it is a problem with directory but i have configured it as i always have

Comment: @LochlanBoils which file exactly can't be found? Please provide the complete error message you are getting.

Comment: when i build there are no errors. When i go to view output i get the message: "There was an error opening this document the file cannot be found''

Comment: @LochlanBoils this seems to be a problem between your editor and your viewer (not directly related to LaTeX), Unfortunately, I don't use TeXnicCenter so I can'y help you here more. However, check if you can open the `.pdf` file going to the file where it resides and if the result is expected.

Comment: No worries i'll figure it out, if you could post the output of the graph for now that would be great

Comment: @LochlanBoils sure! I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should serve as a starting point for you. I have hard coded every thing so that it will look some what simple (though bulky).

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel=Time $\rightarrow$,ylabel=$S(t) \rightarrow$]
    \foreach \xStart/\xEnd  in {0/.1, .2/.3, .4/.5, .6/.7,.8/.9} {
        \addplot[domain=\xStart:\xEnd, blue, samples=10, ultra thick] {10};
    }   
    %draw discontinuos lines
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .1, 10) -- (axis cs: .1, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .2, 10) -- (axis cs: .2, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .3, 10) -- (axis cs: .3, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .4, 10) -- (axis cs: .4, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .5, 10) -- (axis cs: .5, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .6, 10) -- (axis cs: .6, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .7, 10) -- (axis cs: .7, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .8, 10) -- (axis cs: .8, 3);
    \draw [draw=red, dotted, thin] (axis cs: .9, 10) -- (axis cs: .9, 3);
    % Show discontinuty points
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: .1, 10) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: .3, 10) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: .5, 10) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: .7, 10) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=white, thick] (axis cs: .9, 10) circle (2.0pt);
    \foreach \xStart/\xEnd  in {.1/.2, .3/.4, .5/.6, .7/.8,.9/1} {
        \addplot[domain=\xStart:\xEnd, blue, samples=10, ultra thick] {3};
    }
    % Show discontinuty points
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs: .1, 3) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs: .3, 3) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs: .5, 3) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs: .7, 3) circle (2.0pt);
    \draw [draw=blue, fill=blue, thick] (axis cs: .9, 3) circle (2.0pt);    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]