# Drawing piecewise linear plots with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to draw something like the following (which was done in Mathematica) in pgfplots, but I can't find a way to define a piecewise linear function and have pgfplots get the full and empty circles correct. I could probably get something close by doing a constant plot with right marks, but it feels like there's probably a better way to do it directly. Any ideas appreciated.

[image: Piecewise linear plot]

Comment: It looks like what you have is pretty good!

Comment: Thanks, but I did the above with Mathematica not pgfplots -- sorry for the confusion. I'll mention that in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: ["What is the clearest way to graph a piecewise function?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/what-is-the-clearest-way-to-graph-a-piecewise-function/63028#63028).

Comment: Indeed -- thanks for sharing that DJP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways: first, definig a function and plotting each piece separately, as was suggested in [What is the clearest way to graph a piecewise function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/what-is-the-clearest-way-to-graph-a-piecewise-function/63028#63028); second , using two plots (the first approach might seem an overkill here):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x) = (\x<0.5) * (1)  +  and(\x>0.5, \x<1) * (0);
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits
]
\foreach \start/\end  in {0/0.5, 0.5/1} 
  \addplot[domain=\start:\end,blue,thick,samples=10] {func(x)};
\draw[blue,fill=blue] 
  (axis cs:0.5,1) circle (2pt);
\draw[blue,fill=white] 
  (axis cs:0.5,0) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits
]
\foreach \start/\end/\Func  in {0/0.5/1, 0.5/1/0} 
  \addplot[domain=\start:\end,blue,thick,samples=10] {\Func};
\draw[blue,fill=blue] 
  (axis cs:0.5,1) circle (2pt);
\draw[blue,fill=white] 
  (axis cs:0.5,0) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The filled and "empty" dots can be produced using small circles placed at the desired location using the `axis` cs coordinate system. If you want to see the axis beneath the empty dot, add `axis on top`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    func(\x) = (\x<0.5) * (1)  +  and(\x>0.5, \x<1) * (0);
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits,
  axis on top
]
\foreach \start/\end  in {0/0.5, 0.5/1} 
  \addplot[domain=\start:\end,blue,thick,samples=10] {func(x)};
\draw[blue,fill=blue] 
  (axis cs:0.5,1) circle (2pt);
\draw[blue,fill=white] 
  (axis cs:0.5,0) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=middle,
  enlargelimits,
  axis on top
]
\foreach \start/\end/\Func  in {0/0.5/1, 0.5/1/0} 
  \addplot[domain=\start:\end,blue,thick,samples=10] {\Func};
\draw[blue,fill=blue] 
  (axis cs:0.5,1) circle (2pt);
\draw[blue,fill=white] 
  (axis cs:0.5,0) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]