# How to hide coordinates on the x and y axis from graphs plotted by pst-plot

Tags: diagrams, plot, pst-plot

The following code taken [from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63026/106851)

```
\documentclass[border=0bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=yellow,opacity=0.5](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(3.5,1.5)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
    \pscustom
    {
        \psplot{-2.5}{-1}{0}
        \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
        \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
        \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
        \psplot{2}{3.5}{1}
    }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

I wonder how to hide the numbers and the small verticle line from x any y axes? I only want lines with arrows.

Comment: Add `ticks=none, labels=none` as options to the `\psaxes` macro.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks! How do I hide them just for x-axis or y-axis alone? If this is complicated, I will add my question body to ask it more formally.

Comment: I would not say that it is overly complicated .... If you only want ticks and labels on the y axis, add `ticks=y, labels=y`, if you only want ticks and labels on the x axis, add `ticks=x, labels=x`. Maybe have a look at the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/doc/pst-plot-doc.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the options `ticks` and `labels` to the `\psaxes` macro. The options can take different keys, such as `all`, `none`, `x` and `y`. Using, for example `ticks=none, labels=none` would hide all ticks and all labels. Using `ticks=y, labels=y` would show ticks and labels only on the y axis. For more information about such options, I'd suggest to have a look in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/doc/pst-plot-doc.pdf).

```
\documentclass[border=10mm,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=yellow,opacity=0.5](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray,ticks=none,labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(3.5,1.5)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
    \pscustom
    {
        \psplot{-2.5}{-1}{0}
        \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
        \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
        \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
        \psplot{2}{3.5}{1}
    }
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=yellow,opacity=0.5](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray,ticks=x,labels=x]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(3.5,1.5)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
    \pscustom
    {
        \psplot{-2.5}{-1}{0}
        \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
        \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
        \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
        \psplot{2}{3.5}{1}
    }
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psframe*[linecolor=yellow,opacity=0.5](-2.75,-0.75)(4,2)
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray,ticks=y,labels=y]{->}(0,0)(-2.5,-0.5)(3.5,1.5)[$t$,0][$F(t)$,90]
    \psset{algebraic,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red}
    \pscustom
    {
        \psplot{-2.5}{-1}{0}
        \psplot{-1}{0}{(x+1)/4}
        \psplot{0}{1}{1/2}
        \psplot{1}{2}{(x+7)/12}
        \psplot{2}{3.5}{1}
    }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]