# Can't use \pgfmathdeclarefunction even though I use package pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use pgfmathdeclarefunction to create define a new pgf function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-do-i-use-pgfmathdeclarefunction-to-create-define-a-new-pgf-function)

I'm running the simple code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathand{\pgfmathless{#1}{1}} {\pgfmathgreater{#1}{0}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot {p(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get:

> ! Undefined controlsequence.
>
> 1.4 \pgfmathdeclarefunction

Any ideas what might be wrong? Other examples with pgf seem to work just fine.

If it helps, I'm using TexShop for mac. I have the most recent version.

Comment: I don't get the error you describe, but get `! Extra \else. \pgfmath@operation@@process` Following [defining-a-piecewise-function-for-pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19510/defining-a-piecewise-function-for-pgfplots) and using `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{\pgfmathparse{(and(#1>0, #1<1)*1)}}` everything works fine. Is your tex distribution up to date?
`

Comment: I'm usin Texshop for mac. I just downloaded the last version but I still get the same error.

Comment: `TeXShop` is just an editor, not the tex distribution that does the actual typesetting.  And [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has something to do with expansion when using the `\pgfmath...` type functions within other `\pgfmth...`.

But what does work is if you rewrite the function as:

```
 \pgfmathand{less({#1},1)}{greater({#1},0)}
```

This yields:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{p}{1}{%
  \pgfmathand{less({#1},1)}{greater({#1},0)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot {p(x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: or with `\pgfmathparse{and(less(#1,1),greater(#1,0))}`

Comment: @Altermundus: Yep, or as per cmhughes' comment above. I was trying to keep it as close to the original post..

Answer (score 1):

So it wasn't a problem with TexShop but a problem with TikZ. `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` is only available on the latest build.

Installing the package again should solve the problem.

[Download Tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/)

Comment: The builds found at TeXample are somewhat old, [Altermundus](http://www.altermundus.com/pages/builds/index.html) have more recent builds. Also, `\pgfmathdeclarefunction` is found in the latest stable versions I believe (the build above is a development version), so simply updating your TeX distribution should help.