# PGF loop - how to use an array inside pgfmathdeclare function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I'd like to pick a number from my array inside a loop. The first argument is a "starting" value which increments by 1 for each iteration based on the second and third argument (`\qa`). The maximum number of iterations can be determined by the second argument (`\eval@limit`). The other maximum value can be determined by the value of the third argument (`\arbitraryarrayvalue`).

I'm running into some issues using my array inside `\pgfmathdeclarefunction`. Specifically:
The first case, the easy one, is to simply put:

```
\pgfmathparse{\myarray[\arbitraryarrayvalue]}
\pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
```

Before closing the group. It turns out I can't look inside the array:

```
Paragraph ended before \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

So looking at the existing questsions I found one related question to `\pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat`, at [How do I use pgfmathdeclarefunction to create define a new pgf function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/how-do-i-use-pgfmathdeclarefunction-to-create-define-a-new-pgf-function/15437#15437).

I couldn't make the inference from that question to the solution of mine.

So second case: if I use the array inside my `Expl3` solution for comparisons (this solution you will also find in the code below), I get an error like this one:

```
File ended while scanning use of \__fp_parse_after:ww.
Emergency stop.
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

So judging from the fact they both refer to "file ended while doing something", I suspect these macro's keep reading further and expanding further until the document ends, which I *usually* solve with a well-placed `\relax`. I've tried adding that all over the place (inside the comparison, after it, about the array, etc.), but I can't seem to get rid of the error.

Possibly not so related but maybe a general solution *outside* `expl3` would be the answer (?) regardless, I would like to see how a such general solution to break the loop would look like outside `expl3`. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \breakloop #1 #2
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnT { #1 } > { #2 }
      { \breakforeach }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\global\def\myarray{{5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60}}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{blah}{3}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#1} % starting value
    \edef\qa{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#2} % maximum amount of loops
    \edef\eval@limit{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#3+1} % maximum value of array
    \edef\arbitraryarrayvalue{\pgfmathresult}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\eval@limit}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{\qa+1} % \qa += 1
      \global\edef\q@{\pgfmathresult} %
      \pgfmathparse{\q@} %
      \global\edef\qa{\pgfmathresult} %
      \breakloop{\qa}{\myarray[\arbitraryarrayvalue]}
    }
    \pgfmathparse{\qa}
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{blah(1,1000,9)}\pgfmathresult    %

\pgfmathparse{\myarray[2]}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is solved by evaluating the array element first.  Getting the element requires you pass an integer as an index, not a number in fixed point notation.  I have moved the evaluation of the array element outside the loop as it does not vary with the iteration.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \breakloop #1 #2
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnT { #1 } > { #2 }
      { \breakforeach }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\gdef\myarray{{5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60}}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{blah}{3}{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfmathparse{#1} % starting value
    \edef\qa{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#2} % maximum amount of loops
    \edef\eval@limit{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{#3+1} % maximum value of array
    \edef\arbitraryarrayvalue{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfmathparse{\myarray[\arbitraryarrayvalue]}
    \edef\qb{\pgfmathresult}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\eval@limit}
    {
      \pgfmathparse{\qa+1} % \qa += 1
      \xdef\q@{\pgfmathresult} %
      \pgfmathparse{\q@} %
      \xdef\qa{\pgfmathresult} %
      \breakloop{\qa}{\qb}
    }
    \pgfmathparse{\qa}
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{blah(1,1000,9)}\pgfmathresult    %

\pgfmathparse{\myarray[4]}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice addition of the shorthand notations `\xdef` and `\gdef`. I also noticed `\gdef` is unneeded for the array ? Which puzzles me a bit considering I just opened a new group, but hey, it works.

Comment: The array is defined at outer level so persists in lower level groups.  The global there could be useful if you later package this up in something else.