# How to generate a graphcis like a flowchart but with function plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that latex plot is really powerful. I think it can also work out for the attached figure as follows. Can I anyone help me out? Similar plot demonstration is also greatly helpful.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: We probably need some more information. I have no clue what a flowchart with function plot is. :) Also please try to supply a MWE for our consideration and further suggestions.

Comment: Yes, of course: see [How to produce John Kruschke's Bayesian model diagrams using TikZ or similar tools?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55869/13304)

Comment: @zeroth: Maybe this special flowchart shown in figure can be seen as one in which function plot is a node/box shape but without boundary line. I know how to creat flowchart, but I don't know how to fill function plot in box/node and remove the box boundary line. If I know, it will become easy.

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino: Thanks for the provided link. I need some time to understand the code.

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed. Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried: you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.