# Add a gaussian curve in a specific location in a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to put a gaussian curve in a specific location in a diagram I am creating with tikz.

I found the question [Bell Curve/Gaussian Function in TikZ/PGF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11368/bell-curve-gaussian-function-in-tikz-pgf), and I can use this to add the gaussian curve to my diagram, but I don't know how to put it in the proper place. The gaussian should be centered at (0,10) in the tikz diagram. Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\phcy}{3.5}

% draw beam and dimension
\draw[line width=2] (0,\phcy) -- +(-3,10) ;
\draw[line width=2] (0,\phcy) -- +(3,10) ;
\draw[line width=1.5,<->] (0,\phcy) ++(73.6:10) arc (73.6:106.3:10);
\node at (0,\phcy+9.5) {$\Theta_{FWHM}$};

\begin{axis}[style={samples=200,smooth},
    axis lines=none]
\addplot[mark=none] {gauss(0,1)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add `anchor=origin, at={(0,10cm)}` to the `axis` options to position the plot. Do you also want the plot to have a specific width/height?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Thank you Jake! Yes, I think I will want it to have a specific height/width. What makes the most sense to me is to set things so that a gauss(0,1) has a \sigma of 1 cm. I can't really tell by eye whether that's happening now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add `anchor=origin, at={(0,10cm)}` to the `axis` options to position the plot. To make the width of the plot correspond to the units of the drawing, you can also set `x=1cm` in the `axis`

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\phcy}{3.5}

% draw beam and dimension
\draw[line width=2] (0,\phcy) -- +(-3,10) ;
\draw[line width=2] (0,\phcy) -- +(3,10) ;
\draw[line width=1.5,<->] (0,\phcy) ++(73.6:10) arc (73.6:106.3:10);
\node at (0,\phcy+9.5) {$\Theta_{FWHM}$};

\begin{axis}[
    anchor=origin,
    x=1cm,
    at={(0,10cm)},
    style={samples=51,smooth},
    hide axis
]
\addplot[mark=none] {gauss(0,1)};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For those curious, this usage of `anchor` and `at` is documented in section 4.18.1 of the PGFPLOTS manual (revision 1.8). The use of `x` to set a distance scale is covered in section 4.9.