# How do I embed a smaller graph in a larger graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I wish to embed a bell-curve in the center of a big circle (hopefully with some flexibility in location) but fail to accomplish that. The following is my current code. Need help! Thanks.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand\gauss[2]{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))} % Gauss function, parameters mu and sigma
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]

\begin{axis}[
      axis x line=none,
      axis y line=none,
      style={mark=,domain=-3:3,samples=50,smooth}, % All plots: from -2:2, 50 samples, smooth, no marks
      ]
\addplot[domain=-3:3, blue, thick]{\gauss{0}{0.75}};

\draw[thick] (0,0.275) circle (2.5cm);
\end{axis};
\end{tikzpicture}      

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128331/add-a-gaussian-curve-in-a-specific-location-in-a-tikz-diagram?r=SearchResults&s=8|54.8788.  I might also add that you can overlap two axis environments in one tikzpicture.  [scale only axis] is useful for that.

Comment: It should be possible to put the gaussian into a `scope` environment within your `tikzpicture`. That scope env can then be moved and scaled independently - check out the Tikz manual for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't involve the `axis` environment, which cause an annoying coordinate shifting:

[image: clip gaussian into a circle]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\gauss[2]{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*2.718^(-((\x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))} % Gauss function, parameters mu and sigma

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
    
        %\draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
        \begin{scope}       
            \clip (0,0) circle (2.5);
            \draw[thick,yshift=-1.75cm,scale=2.5,domain=-3:3, smooth, blue] plot ({\x}, {\gauss{0}{0.28}}); 
        \end{scope}
        
        \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2.5);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}      

\end{document}
```

Of course, you can play with the parameters, the scaling and the `yshift` into the plotting line.