# Plot the poisson function correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was try to plot the Poisson distribution as a discrete graph and only found continuous graph examples like this:

[Poisson distribution with tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170068/poisson-distribution-with-tikzpicture)

Formula is:

&space;0" target="*blank">&space;0" title="P*{\lambda}(k) = \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} \quad for \quad k \in \mathbb{N}_0,\quad \lambda > 0" />

How can I plot the discrete graph? [image: Poisson distribution]

Answer (score 2):

This is how to plot the discrete Poisson function.
Added `ycomb` to [the example from the link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170133/2552), this makes the plot discrete and not continuous.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{poiss}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{(#1^x)*exp(-#1)/(x!)}%
  }
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
              axis x line=center,
              axis y line=center,
              xtick={0,2,...,19},
              ytick={0.1,0.2,...,0.4},
                domain = 0:18,
                samples = 19,
                xlabel={$k$},
                ylabel={$P[k]$},
                xlabel style={right},
                ylabel style={above left},
                ymax=0.5,
                xmax=20,
                x post scale=1.4
                ]
                \addplot+[ycomb,blue,thick] {poiss(1))};
                \addlegendentry{$\lambda = 1$}
                \addplot+[ycomb,red,thick] {poiss(5))};
                 \addlegendentry{$\lambda = 5$}
                \addplot+[ycomb,brown,thick] {poiss(9))};
                 \addlegendentry{$\lambda = 9$};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot of the poisson function]

Comment: while in general a self answer is OK on the site, what is the point here? You ask a question that is too vague for anyone to answer and then immediately post the answer?

Comment: I only found this answer

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170068/poisson-distribution-with-tikzpicture

Which is incorrect, so I wanted to post a correct example how to plot the Poisson distribution

Comment: If I understand correctly, the core difference to the code you linked to is that you added the `ycomb` option, right? Maybe you could add that to your answer so it's clearer for others who come across the same problem?

Comment: The other plot is mathematical incorrect.

Comment: If that answer is incorrect, wouldn't it be better to post a correct answer to that question? And, preferably, leave a comment explaining why the accepted answer is wrong. [There is something wrong with the code in that answer, but that's just a question of a missing curly bracket.] The way you've done this, anybody looking for an answer who finds the other question will have no clue to look for yours, which is a shame if yours is right and the other wrong, as you claim.