# Plotting a chart and chart line?

Tags: pgfplots, plot

How I can Plot this curve in Latex {revtex4-1}?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[bar width=18pt,
 xtick=data,ymin=0,ymax=45,x tick label style=
{rotate=90,anchor=east}]
\addplot[ybar] coordinates{ (126.5  ,2 ) (134.5 ,4 ) (142.5 ,13) (150.5 ,20) (158.5 ,35) (166.5 ,33) (174.5 ,25) (182.5 ,17) (190.5 ,5 ) (198.5 ,3 )  };
\addplot +[smooth,black,mark = *,mark options={solid,black}]coordinates{ (126.5,    1.3 ) (134.5,   4.3 ) (142.5,   11.2) (150.5,   22.6) (158.5,   31.2) (166.5,   33.5) (174.5,   26.9) (182.5,   16.2) (190.5,   7.2 ) (198.5,   2.4 )};
```

[image]

Comment: did you search this site for bar plots?

Comment: yes, but I did not find the answer !

Comment: You can combine http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11368/bell-curve-gaussian-function-normal-distribution-in-tikz-pgf and any barplot question with data is given as a table

Comment: I did this code and there is no error but there is no result !!
the code is 
`\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[bar width=18pt,
    xtick=data,ymin=0,ymax=45,x tick label style=
{rotate=90,anchor=east}]

\addplot[ybar] coordinates{
(126.5 ,2 )
(134.5 ,4 )
(142.5 ,13)
(150.5 ,20)
(158.5 ,35)
(166.5 ,33)
(174.5 ,25)
(182.5 ,17)
(190.5 ,5 )
(198.5 ,3 )

};

\addplot +[smooth,black,mark = *,mark options={solid,black}]coordinates{
(126.5, 1.3 )
(134.5, 4.3 )
(142.5, 11.2)
(150.5, 22.6)
(158.5, 31.2)
(166.5, 33.5)
(174.5, 26.9)
(182.5, 16.2)
(190.5, 7.2 )
(198.5, 2.4 )};`

Comment: Can you please complete your code with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, whatever else you have in your axis, and `\end{document}`?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,aps,nofootinbib,pra,amsmath,amssymb,floatfix]{revtex4-1}` and this is the packages that I useing `\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=297mm,centering,hmargin={1.5cm,1.5cm},vmargin={3cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}`

Answer (score 3):

To get the desired format you can apply:

- `draw=red, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red` to provide the pattern for the fill of the bars
- `marks=none` to eliminate the dots
- `/pgf/number format/fixed` and `/pgf/number format/precision=0` to control the display of the `x ticks labels`, and
- `ylabel={Count} and` xlabel={Time}` to label the axis

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[bar width=18pt,
     xtick=data,ymin=0,ymax=45,
     x tick label style={
         rotate=90,
         anchor=east,
         /pgf/number format/fixed,
         /pgf/number format/precision=0,
         },
         ylabel={Count},
         xlabel={Time},
 ]
\addplot[ybar, draw=red, thick, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red] coordinates{ (126.5  ,2 ) (134.5 ,4 ) (142.5 ,13) (150.5 ,20) (158.5 ,35) (166.5 ,33) (174.5 ,25) (182.5 ,17) (190.5 ,5 ) (198.5 ,3 )  };
\addplot +[smooth,black,mark=none, thick] coordinates{ (126.5,    1.3 ) (134.5,   4.3 ) (142.5,   11.2) (150.5,   22.6) (158.5,   31.2) (166.5,   33.5) (174.5,   26.9) (182.5,   16.2) (190.5,   7.2 ) (198.5,   2.4 )};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: is it same if I used `\documentclass[12pt,aps,nofootinbib,pra,amsmath,amssymb,floatfix]{revtex4-1}` ?